# Why is data value undefined inside of 'Event Bus'?

Tags: vuejs2

```
    data() {
        return {
          cr: "", // Current route
          isAdmin: false
        };
      },        

created() {
        this.cr = this.$router.currentRoute.name;
        console.log(this.isAdmin); // false
        EventBus.$on("logged", function() {
          console.log(this.isAdmin); // undefined
          console.log("isAdmin true!"); // logs just fine!
        });
      }
```

This is part of a Vue app where I use an 'Event Bus' as outlined [here.](https://www.google.com/search?q=vue%20event%20bus&oq=vue%20event%20bus&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j69i60l2j0l2.1878j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

As shown in the inline comments in this code, inside `created()`, I get a value for `this.isAdmin`. However, inside of the *Event Bus* callback, that same value is `undefined` ❓

Comment: I am assuming there is some issue with what `this` is inside of that EventBus callback?

Comment: Yes, I C that doing `this` is different context inside of Event Bus......`console.log(this)` 

Comment: You need an arrow function for the `EventBus.$on("logged", () => { })`.

Comment: Yeah, believe or not, I was just coming in here to post that as the solution. In this case we don't want any 'messing with' of `this` so _fat arrow fxn._ is 